# problem solving this integral of half line dirichlet heat equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am studying heat equations and I am trying to categorize the questions and their general solution as well as techniques to solve them. I reached to this excercise:
for half line $0<x<\infty$
$u_t-u_{xx}=0$
$u(x,0)=sin(2x)$
$u(0,t)=0$
I solved the problem to some point but I am stuck with this integral. I do not know how to solve this:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4t}}sin(2y) \,dy$
I would appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables might make you guess:
$$
          u(x,t)= e^{-4t}\sin(2x)
$$

Comment: Is there any rigorous argument without taking any guess?

Comment: @Stack_Underflow : Separation of variables is rigorous.